# How to get elements from a list that is returned from sapply

Tags: r

I have a list that contains different values that represent the occurrence of an event. For example, assume the list `occValsList` is like:

```
X1=4
X2=11
X3=7
X4=13
X5=2
```

I would like to get only the values that are higher than 10. To do that, I did the following:

```
which(sapply(occValsList, function(y) y > 10))
```

But this returns the index of the elements rather than the values:

```
X2 X4
2  4
```

What I want to return is:

```
X2 X4
11 13
```

How can I do that?

Comment: So remove the `which`. You can do ```l1[sapply(l1, `>`, 10)]```

Comment: Or even `unlist(l[l > 10])`, where `l` is your list.

Comment: With your approach `unlist(occValsList[which(sapply(occValsList, function(y) y > 10))])` would do it, but as pointed out  by others if not for some learning reason the approach you're using is an overkill

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given this list

```
l <- list(
  X1 = 4,
  X2 = 11,
  X3 = 7,
  X4 = 13,
  X5 = 2
)
```

you can do

```
unlist(l[l > 10])
```

which gives this result

```
X2 X4 
11 13
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution for this is to remove the `which()`-function and just index by the `sapply()`-function.

Let's say you created your dataframe like this:

```
occValsList <- list(X1 = 4, X2 = 11, X3 = 7, X4 = 13, X5 = 2)
```

To retrieve the wished information you can now index (`[]`) with the help of `sapply()` and than unlist by using the `unlist()`-function to create the expected output:

```
unlist(occValsList[sapply(occValsList, function(y) y > 10)])
```

Good luck!

Comment: Hi @arg0naut, thanks, didn't notice that. Edited the answer!